# How to know if I should use verb+ing after the word 'to'?

Tags: grammar

I have always been taught that I should use the base form of a verb after the word 'to'. But I sometimes see sentences such as 'I am looking forward to meeting you' & 'She has devoted her life to doing charitable works'. So how to know when to use base form or verb+ing after the word 'to'? Thank you.

Comment: The 'rule' you were taught fails to take account of the different usages of _to_. In 'look forward to [the school holidays]' it is a transitivising particle, in 'try to win' it is the infinitive marker (particle), and in 'went to Blackpool' it is the preposition.

Comment: Related [What is the difference between the two phrases *to meet you* and *meeting you*?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/242759/what-is-the-difference-between-the-two-phrases-to-meet-you-and-meeting-you), and [**“To hear”** or **“to hearing”**?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/18772/to-hear-or-to-hearing)

Comment: Also related: [Looking forward to follow vs. following](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30345/looking-forward-to-follow-vs-following) and [I am looking forward to …? (followed by a Gerund)?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/127554/i-am-looking-forward-to-followed-by-a-gerund/127555#127555) and [Verb + to infinitive or Verb + …ing](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/214148/verb-to-infinitive-or-verb-ing)

Comment: For learning English there are not only dictionaries, but also grammars. The problem is to find the right grammar for your purpose.